# Trabajar con objetos en servicios Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular4

Estoy intentando trabajar con este JSON:

```
{"code":"OK_BEER_100","beers":[{"avaliable":true,"_id":"5a71d971734d1d71dd530b5e","numberbeer":1,"name":"Alhambra 1925 Updated","type":"Baja","origin":"Granada","percent":33.3,"ibus":15,"halfpint":"3.5","fullpint":"5"},{"avaliable":true,"_id":"5a71d9a5734d1d71dd530b6e","numberbeer":2,"name":"Origen","type":"Alta","origin":"Almeria","percent":18,"ibus":5,"halfpint":"4","fullpint":"6.5"},{"avaliable":true,"_id":"5a71d9cd734d1d71dd530b89","numberbeer":3,"name":"Malta Powah","type":"Flipas","origin":"El Congo","percent":99,"ibus":43,"halfpint":"10","fullpint":"12.5"}]}
```

Tengo mi Objeto con dos elementos y dentro de beers contiene 3 objetos mas.

Estoy recuperando el .json en el servicio así:

```
getBeers(){
   console.log("Consumimos el servicio Beers");
   let headers = new Headers ({'Accept': 'application/json'});
   let options = new RequestOptions ({headers : headers});
   return this._http.get(this.url+'getall', options).map(res => res.json());
 }
```

Para el componentes así:

```
this._beerService.getBeers().subscribe(
      response => {
        if(!response){
          console.log('La respuesta esta vacia');
        }else{
          this.beer = response;
          console.log('mostramos el valor: ' + JSON.stringify(this.beer));
          console.log('Mostramos el this.datos: ' + this.beer);
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    );
```

Mi respuesta es esta:

```
mostramos el valor: {"code":"OK_BEER_100","beers":[{"avaliable":true,"_id":"5a71d971734d1d71dd530b5e","numberbeer":1,"name":"Alhambra 1925 Updated","type":"Baja","origin":"Granada","percent":33.3,"ibus":15,"halfpint":"3.5","fullpint":"5"},{"avaliable":true,"_id":"5a71d9a5734d1d71dd530b6e","numberbeer":2,"name":"Origen","type":"Alta","origin":"Almeria","percent":18,"ibus":5,"halfpint":"4","fullpint":"6.5"},{"avaliable":true,"_id":"5a71d9cd734d1d71dd530b89","numberbeer":3,"name":"Malta Powah","type":"Flipas","origin":"El Congo","percent":99,"ibus":43,"halfpint":"10","fullpint":"12.5"}]}
```

El Objeto

```
pizarra.component.ts:32 Mostramos el this.datos: [object Object]
```

Me he creado un modelo con la siguiente información:

```
export class Beers{
  constructor(
    public avaliable: string,
    public _id: number,
    public numberbeer: number,
    public name: string,
    public type: string,
    public origin: string,
    public percent:  string,
    public ibus: string,
    public halfpint: string,
    public fullpint:string
  ){}
}
```

Pero cuando intento asignar la respuesta con esos datos me indica que no encuentra información.

```
public beer: Beers;
this.beer = response.beer;
```

Tengo que diseñar dos modelos uno para el primer objeto y otro para los otros objetos pero asignando beers a ese objeto?

por ejemplo:

```
import { Beers } from './beers';
export class Objeto{
  constructor(
    public code: string,
    public beers: Beers
    ){}
}
```

Todo lo que encuentro es para JSON a full sin los objetos principales.

El principal objetivo de esto es rellenar en la parte de html con un ngfor con los datos de las beer

**Edit**

Entonces una duda en el caso de tener un JSON con varios Objetos por ejemplo así

```
{"var_RadiacionExt": [
        {
            "attrName": "var_RadiacionExt",
            "attrValue": "8",
            "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:57:45.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "var_RadiacionGlobalInt": [
        {
            "attrName": "var_RadiacionGlobalInt",
            "attrValue": "8",
            "recvTime": "2018-02-02T13:57:45.000Z"
        }
    ]}.
```

¿Que tendría que asignar a cada `this.miData1 = response.var_RadiacionGlobalInt;` y  `this.miData2 = response.var_RadiacionExt;` o en este caso al tener la misma estructura interior no se asigna la respuesta a cada una de ellas y se hace completo? `this.beer = response;`

En este caso estoy haciendo esto:

```
this.miData = response;
let var_RadiacionExt: Inver[] = this.miData.var_RadiacionExt;
let var_RadiacionGlobalInt: Inver[] = this.miData.var_RadiacionGlobalInt;
```

y así asigno los valores:

```
this.Tempint = var_TempInt[0].attrValue;
this.RHint = var_HumRInt[0].attrValue
```

Es correcto? así funciona.

Comment: No tengo claro tu escenario: *Pero cuando intento asignar la respuesta con esos datos me indica que no encuentra información.* ¿A qué te refieres?, ¿dónde más estás tratando de guardar o usar la respuesta?

Comment: Perdona que no lo he comentado.
mi idea es rellenar una tabla en la parte de html con un ngfor con los datos de las beers. A lo que me refiero es que cuando hago el console.log de this.beer me da this.beer: undefined

Comment: Posiblemente estés accediendo antes de tener la respuesta

Comment: Hola, yo creo que lo estoy haciendo en orgen: this.beer = response.beer;
          console.log('mostramos el valor: ' + JSON.stringify(this.beer));
          console.log('Mostramos el this.datos: ' + this.beer);

Comment: Me refiero a que tu componente está intentando mostrar algo en pantalla sin tener el dato todavía

Comment: Veo que `this.beer` no es un array de `Beers`. Probaste de la siguiente forma, creo que tu error podría estar ahí `public beer: Beers[];
this.beer = response.beers;`

Comment: Buenas, acabo de caer en una cosa con respecto a la respuesta de @FedericoMadoery, el nombre de la variable public beers: Beers; tiene que ser el mismo que el del objeto que quiero leer?. supongo que si ya que lo he cambiado y me da error y si lo pongo igual funciona y ahora muestra  [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]. que es la informacion del objeto beers. He probado con [] y sin ellos donde comenta Federico y me devuelve lo mismo.

Comment: Tu accedías a `.beer`, mientras en el JSon, figuraba "beers:". Eso si cuenta

Comment: Vale ahora entiendo esto, he editado el post con una pregunta.